# Haskell notation for composing two functions f and g where g takes multiple arguments

Tags: haskell, operators, variadic-functions, currying, function-composition

Often I find I want to compose two functions f and g, but g takes multiple arguments.  Does Haskell provide a set of operators for that (I know I could write it myself, but it seems fairly common and I don't want to duplicate an operator that already exists in Haskell)

ie something like

```
(.@) = (.)
(.@@) f g x1 x2 = f $ g x1 x2
(.@@@) f g x1 x2 x3 = f $ g x1 x2 x3
(.@@@@) f g x1 x2 x3 x4 = f $ g x1 x2 x3 x4
...
```

up to some reasonable number of arguments

Comment: You might be interested in the [composition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition-1.0.1.0/docs/Data-Composition.html) library

Comment: Could you please make a concrete example?

Comment: @bheklilr Thanks, that's the answer I was looking for.  It's (.:) (.::) etc.  I tried googling "haskell compose function multiple arguments" but google didn't give any useful links

Comment: @dspyz No problem.  To be honest, I normally just define `.:` in my code whenever I need it, since it requires fewer characters than setting up the library and importing that one function.  If I need `.::`, then I'll pull in the library.  Another interesting tidbit is that the `.:` operator is a more specific version of `fmap fmap fmap`, which has the type `(Functor f, Functor g) => (a -> b) -> f (g a) -> f (g b)`, and can be used in useful circumstances like `(+1) .: [Just 1, Nothing] === [Just 2, Nothing]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you got the answer you wanted, but I wanted to point out that these combinators have the following cute implementation:

```
(.:)   = (.) . (.)
(.:.)  = (.) . (.) . (.)
(.::)  = (.) . (.) . (.) . (.)
(.::.) = (.) . (.) . (.) . (.) . (.)
```

and if you only need them fully applied:

```
f .: g   = (f .) . g
f .:. g  = ((f .) .) . g
f .:: g  = (((f .) .) .) . g
f .::. g = ((((f .) .) .) .) . g
```

It doesn't seem so terrible to use these expressions directly, without defining an operator. At least the first one, `(f .) . g`, seems readable enough to me.

Comment: Wow! I love this, but I'm totally lost.  Would you mind explaining this in baby steps?  I can't figure out how to unpack it.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out after moving everything to prefix notation and evaluating (.) (.) (.) f g x y just unthinkingly replacing (.) f g x expressions with f (g x) until I arrived at f (g x y)

Answer (score 5):

From @bheklilr 's comment, the answer I was looking for is in the composition library: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/composition-1.0.1.0/docs/Data-Composition.html

The functions (.:), (.:.), (.::), (.::.) etc. do exactly what I was thinking